# If $f\in L^1([0,\infty ))$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{[0,n]}xf(x)dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function such that $\int_{[0,\infty]}\left |f(x)\right |dx<+\infty$ (Lebesgue's integral). Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{[0,n]}xf(x)dx=0$

Comment: I tried viewing trivial cases, for example if $f$ is the characteristic function of some interval, in that case it is obvious. Then I tried to extend to any open subset of $[0,\infty)$ which is a numerable union of disjoint intervals but I couldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for every $x \in [0,\infty)$, we have
$$
\underbrace{\left|\frac{xf(x)\mathcal{X}_{[0,n]}}{n}\right|}_{\triangleq f_n(x)}\leq |f(x)|
$$

and $f_n(x) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ (as for every given $x$, $\frac{xf(x)}{n}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$). Finally, since $f \in L^1$, we have by dominated convergence theorem that
$$
0 = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,\infty)}\frac{1}{n}xf(x)\mathcal{X}_{[0,n]}dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{[0,n]}xf(x)dx.
$$